# Flattening nested attributes in Jackson

Tags: java, json

I have the need of defining a flat POJO that maps its (flat) attributes to a nested object in its JSON specification. Better explain with code

```
{
    "offset": 0,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "filter": {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2": true,
        ....
    }
}
```

My POJO shall look like the following:

```
public class Pojo {
    private int offset;
    private int pageSize;

    private String key1;
    private boolean key2;
}
```

So far I have tried annotating those `key` properties with `@JsonProperty` with its `value` attribute

```
@JsonProperty("filter.key1")
private String key1;
```

But when I went into the MVC controller those properties, though set in JSON, were null in the decoded POJO.

How can I fix this? What did I do wrong?

I absolutely don't want to create nested subclasses

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Might** be currently impossible.

This because Jackson currently supports `@JacksonUnwrapped` for the opposite case, but no `@JacksonWrapped`

Feature request: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/issues/42

Comment: In Jackon 2.9 this annotation has name `@JsonUnwrapped`. See:
http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html

Answer (score 1):

[Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values) suggests using a setter or deserializer.  The setter seems much easier so I will only include that solution.

Here is the setter solution.  The quick code below does not prevent `NullPointerException`s due to unboxing the `Boolean`.

```
@JsonProperty("filter")
private void unpackNested(Map<String,Object> filter)
{
    key1 = (String) filter.get("key1");
    key2 = (Boolean) filter.get("key2");
}
```