# Deserializing nested JSON with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to deserialize nested JSON into a single DTO in a Spring Boot application.
The JSON:

```
{"productId": "xyz123",
 "description": "some_description",
 "value": "123",
 "boughtOnDate": "2020-05-20 14:22:58.000662",
 "details": {
   "material": "some_material",
   /// another 20 entries
  }
}
```

The DTO:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
public class Item {
  @Id
  private String productId;
  private String description;
  private Integer value;
  private Timestamp boughtOnDate;
  private String material;
  // another 20 fields that are in the nested part of the json

  // getters & setters
```

The current solution I have is to unpack nested json in the Item class like so:

```
@JsonProperty("details")
private void unpackNestedJson(Map<String, Object> details) {
  this.material = (String) details.get("material");
  // and another 20 lines for unpackacking the rest from the nested part
```

While unpackNestedJson works fine and does its job, it feels cumbersome as there is a lot of data to unpack from the nested part of the JSON (all entries below and above 'details' from JSON should go as fields into Item entity class only). My question would be - is there a more simple/elegant way of unpacking the nested JSON into a single DTO? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flattening nested attributes in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128383/flattening-nested-attributes-in-jackson)

Comment: I don't believe it does. The documentation specifies that properties are included (serialized/deserialized) as properties of its containing Object. In my case, all JSON properties should go as fields into one class (the data in the nested part under 'details' goes into Item class). If there was another entity class like Details, then sure @JsonUnwrapped would work.

Comment: The reason I suggested it is because that question's answer states that what you're asking for is *not* possible using annotations (only the reverse is) :) Which means you're stuck with your current approach

Answer (score 0):

No, i think that's the right way to do, but if you want to explore another option, you could have an Details object inside Item with a material property. Then you could just have some getters/setters with the parent DTO delegating to the material property to still achieve the same behavior.