# Jackson serializer for ValueObject hierarchy - polymorphic

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, json-serialization

As a continuation of [jackson-serialize-simple-one-attribute-valueobject-like-enum-without-nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050539/jackson-serialize-simple-one-attribute-valueobject-like-enum-without-nesting)

I would like to be able to create Wrapping one attribute ValueObjects in a very simple manner, just by inheriting from base ValueObject class:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ValueObjectJsonSerializer.class)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public abstract class BaseValueObject<T> { 

  T value;
  .......
}
// I want to be able to create multiple ValueObject wrapping Types like
public class Name extends ValueObject<String> {}
public class Surname extends ValueObject<String>{}
public class Age extends ValueObject<Integer>{} 
etc...
```

Is it possible at all?

Is implementing

```
    public void serializeWithType(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers,
                              TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException
```

sufficient for it, or it has to be done some other way?

Where could I find some simple sample serializeWithType implementation?

Maybe base classes should overwrite some method returning actual type descriminator?

Do I also have to implement deserializer to be able deserialize such jsons?

Comment: Could you please create a simple use case how you would like to use these classes? I do not understand what is the real problem and why do you want to implement `serializeWithType` method. Also, what is the difference between `Name` and `Surname` classes? They look almost the same. If `BaseValueObject` would not be an `abstract` class you could delete them and create wrapper instances using this base type.

Comment: Michal, imagine a method findByMultipleProperties(.... Name name, Surname surname, ....) and findByMultipleProperties(String..., String ...., String name, String surname, String ..., String ....). In second case it's very stresfull - for these who care, or error prone - in case of those who don't care - calling findByMultipleProperties(...., person.name, person.surname, .....). I would like to have a very simple way (like in case of eg Name) of creating such WrapperValueObjects, but I would also like them to serialize nicely, so that look of json weren't arugment against using value objects.

Answer (score 0):

Below implementation can serialize polymorphic types, still deserializer remains.
I wonder how jackson serializes and deserializes Java Enums that it doesn't have to include their type in json. This would be what I am interested in. OnePropertyValueObject could be serialized and deserialized like enum.

```
@Slf4j
class ValueObjectJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            gen.writeNull();
            return;
        }
        Class clazz = value.getClass();
        while (clazz != Object.class) {
            java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields = value.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            if (fields.length > 1) {
                throw new IOException(
                    "Do not use this serializer for the class " + value.getClass().getSimpleName() + " which has at least " + fields.length +
                        " fields!");
            } else if (fields.length == 1) {

                final Field first = fields[0];
                try {
                    final Object fieldValue = first.get(value);
                    gen.writeObject(fieldValue);
                    log.info("field {} value: {}", fields[0], fieldValue);
                    return;
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new IOException(e);
                }
            } else {
                clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
            }
        }

        throw new IOException(
            "Do not use this serializer for the class " + value.getClass().getSimpleName() + " which has no fields!");

    }

    public void serializeWithType(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers,
                                  TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException
    {
        if (value == null) {
            gen.writeNull();
            return;
        }
        Class clazz = value.getClass();
        while (clazz != Object.class) {
            java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
            if (fields.length > 1) {
                throw new IOException(
                    "Do not use this serializer for the class " + value.getClass().getSimpleName() + " which has at least " + fields.length + " fields!");
            } else if (fields.length == 1) {

                final Field first = fields[0];
                try {
                    final Object fieldValue = first.get(value);

                    WritableTypeId typeIdDef = typeSer.writeTypePrefix(gen,
                        typeSer.typeId(value, value.getClass(), JsonToken.VALUE_STRING));
                    gen.writeObject(fieldValue);
                    typeSer.writeTypeSuffix(gen, typeIdDef);
                    log.info("field {} value: {}", fields[0], fieldValue);
                    return;
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new IOException(e);
                }
            } else {
                clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
            }
        }

        throw new IOException(
            "Do not use this type serializer for the class " + value.getClass().getSimpleName() + " which has no fields!");
    }

    public JsonTypeInfo.As getTypeInclusion() {
        return JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT;
    }
}
```